# Keyword density importance for keyphrase vs keyword

Tags: keywords

If i need to optimize page for the keyphrase which consists of 4 words

e.g. *"keyword density best practice"*.

What if the the keyword density of the phrase *"keyword density"* is over optimized(e.g.40%).

Would keyword stuffing for *"keyword density"* phrase be considered while ranking page for the query *"keyword density best practice"*?

Comment: Best thing you can do is throw away those oldschool SEO guides your reading, keyword density is not an issue, just don't over do it and write for your audience, not the search engines.

Comment: At 40% I can't imagine it would even be readable? Unless you don't have much content? ... I would have thought that if a page is seen as "keyword stuffing" then it would be penalised for all searches, not just for phrases that contain the _stuffed keywords_?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will affect the "keyword density". and remember the keywords stuffing has diminishing return, If you are a keyword twice or thrice it will give you juice but after that it will not until it start effecting your website in negative direction. I suggest that you should use exact keyword only once that try to diversity by using keyword in way like "best practice for keyword density"

Matt cutts official video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rk4qgQdp2UA